# Git merge and keep separate?

Tags: git

Is there a way to update a side branch with information from another (master or other), and then have the two continue? Like a rebase, but keeping the old data there?

Original:

```
A---B---C---G---H  master
     \           
      D---E---F  branchA
```

Result:

```
A---B---C---G---H---L  master
     \           \
      D---E---F---J---K  branchA
```

Such that `branchA` gets the information from commits C, G, and H, (Commit J is that merge) such that commit K is still a side branch (and future commit L is still on master), but has the updated information from master?

I don't want to do a rebase, because that would end up with:

```
A---B---C---G---H---L  master
                 \
                  D'---E'---F'---K  branchA
```

Creating "new versions" of D, E, and F as if they happened on top of H instead of B, and **the issue is that commits C and E is the renaming of a key folder in the repo, and I want to collapse them together**, without merging the other feature updates from `branchA` just yet. Rebasing means H uses the new folder name, D' creates the old folder name, and E' removes it again, which isn't the most clean.

The point is I want to get that folder rename (C and E) in the past and stop bringing it forward. Does that makes sense? Am I looking at this backward? Or should I just deal with the messy rebase "name, rename" trick until the branch gets merged?

Comment: git merge is the simplest answer; I was experiencing it merging the two branches together, and unable to continue the two separately... But that's not happening now!

Comment: I too thought that `git merge` had merged two branches together, instead of simply merging changes *into* a single branch. But then I discovered that I had unknowingly created a topic branch – *B* – while I had another topic branch – *A* – checked-out, and then I merged *B* into *master*, not realizing that I was also merging all of the commits in *A*!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If your history goes up to H or L on master and F on branchA (that is, J and K do not yet exist), then yes, simply check out branch A and merge:

```
git checkout branchA
git merge H   # Use H's commit identifier if it's not the tip of master
```

This will merge the changes into branchA and will not disturb the master branch at all.

If you have already created commit K and you want to insert a merge between it and F, then there's a bit more work to do:

```
git checkout -b temp F   # Create a new branch at commit F
git merge H              # Merge from commit H into the new branch
git cherry-pick K        # Apply the K commit to the merged commit

# And the rest simply replaces the temp branch with branchA
git checkout branchA
git reset --hard temp
git branch -d temp
```

In both cases, if you later merge in either direction, commit H will be the nearest common ancestor of both history branches, and so future merges will not look past this commit (or past J to F either) when deciding how to merge.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `git merge master` on `branchA` should do (or `git merge H` where `H` is H's commit-ref if `H` is not the latest on master).

There will be conflicts if both `C` and `E` rename the same folder which you will have to resolve, but other than that, you should be fine.